# Ensemble mean of an equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes

I want to find the ensemble mean of an equation $\frac{dA}{dt}=-\beta A+c$. where $A$ is a r.v. and can be written as sum of mean and fluctuation, i.e., $A=E[A]+A'$. $\beta$ and $c$ are some constant parameters. So with this, I can write the ensemble mean of the equation as:

$E \left[ \frac{d\left(E[A]+A'\right)}{dt}\right]=-\beta~ E\left[E[A]+A' \right]+c.$  which leads to

$ \frac{d (E[A])}{dt}=-\beta E[A]+c.$    $~~$ because $E[A']=0$

Is it the correct way to take the ensemble mean of an equation with a r.v. or an SDE?

Comment: If $\beta$ is a constant then this approach is correct.

Comment: @NN2 Thank you for clarification.